# Why does File and Print Sharing Fail after creating Hyper-V External Virtual Switch?

Tags: hyper-v, file-sharing

I'm running a couple of VMs under Hyper-V that I use for testing. I created an "External" Virtual Switch using my NIC so that the VMs would have access to the Internet along with the host PC--the VMs and the host could all access the Internet after creating the switch. However, File and Print Sharing to the host from other PCs in my network quit working; the host in this case is also used as a file server.

I went through the Network troubleshooting from the another box trying to connect to the host and got, "file and print sharing resource is online but isn't responding to connection attempts."

I did find this [article](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/when-hyper-v-external-virtual-network-switches-disrupt-network-connectivity.html), which says:

> [When] you create an External virtual network switch with the name
>   "ExtSwitch" and map this virtual switch to a physical network adapter
>   named "Intel(R) 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network." When you click the
>   Apply button, the following changes are processed in the property of
>   the physical network adapter:
>
> - Unbinds the following services, protocols, and clients: Client for Microsoft Networks, File and Print Sharing for Microsoft Networks,
>     TCP/IP Protocol IPv4, TCP/IP Protocol IPv6, any other service, client
>     or protocol listed in the physical network adapter property.
> - Bind the "Microsoft Virtual Network Switch Protocol"
>
> In addition, the changes below are done in the property of the
>   External virtual network switch, in this case ExtSwitch:
>
> - Bind the following Services, protocols, and clients: Client for Microsoft Networks, File and Print Sharing for Microsoft Networks,
>     TCP/IP Protocol IPv4 and TCP/IP Protocol IPv6.
> - Unbind the "Microsoft Virtual Network Switch Protocol."

It looks like, "File and Print Sharing for Microsoft Networks" should get re-bound to the new external switch.

I should note that I have recently applied the Creators update to all of my machines.

What is it about using a NIC for a Hyper-V External Virtual Switch that breaks File and Print Sharing over that same connection?

Comment: did you find a way to solve this? I tried enabling `File and Print Sharing for Microsoft Networks` on the bridge interface, but checkbox gets removed after saving

Comment: See my answer. Disabling IPv6 in my router resolved the problem for me. I was disabling/re-enabling File & Print sharing on each network adapter that supported it before this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR**: Disabling IPv6 in my router resolved the problem.

My workaround was to run this PowerShell script whenever I restarted my PC running HyperV:

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

# $name = "Ethernet 3"
$script:compid = "ms_server"

function Update-Binding
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance[]]
        $bindings
    )
    Process
    {
        # $bindings.Count

        foreach ($binding in $bindings)
        {
            write-output ("Before disabling {0}" -f $binding.name)
            Get-NetAdapterBinding -Name $binding.name -ComponentId $script:compid

            Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name $binding.name -ComponentId $script:compid

            write-output ("After disabling {0}" -f $binding.name)
            Get-NetAdapterBinding -Name $binding.name -ComponentId $script:compid

            Start-Sleep -Seconds 3

            Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name $binding.name -ComponentId $script:compid

            write-output ("After re-enabling {0}" -f $binding.name)
            Get-NetAdapterBinding -Name $binding.name -ComponentId $script:compid
        }
    }
}

<#
 # Get all ms_server bindings
 #>
Update-Binding -bindings (Get-NetAdapterBinding | ? { $_.ComponentID -eq $script:compid })
```

File shares would work on the network after doing this.

However, I use a WRT1900AC router and read somewhere (It's been awhile and I can't find the reference.) that IPv6 was causing problems when enabled on this router. So, I disabled IPv6 in my router and everything started working again. Maybe you network gurus can explain why this would be so.

I'd like to try another router with IPv6 enabled to see if the problem is isolated to the WRT1900AC but I haven't been able to.